# Autoplay YouTube videos in WPF with Chromium

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium

I'm trying to get an embedded YouTube video to play automatically when the page is loaded. I use this WPF code to set up my browser:

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1"/>
```

The parameter `?autoplay=1` doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [autoplay](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) policy was changed by Google to give users more control over media playback.

If you do do not need sound, you can add the `mute` parameter and set it to `1`, which will allow for autoplay.

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&mute=1"/>
```

If you need autoplay with sound you have to overwrite the `autoplay-policy` in the settings. If you already have a settings initialization in your code, just add the following lines.

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["autoplay-policy"] = "no-user-gesture-required";
```

If you do not use settings, yet, add these lines to the constructor of your WPF application in `App.xaml.cs`.

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["autoplay-policy"] = "no-user-gesture-required";
Cef.Initialize(settings, true, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

Comment: is there any way to add some controls to it? For instance, pause, play, lower/higher volume, mute/unmute via hotkeys.

Comment: I am not sure about that. Maybe you should post a separate question on that issue.